# How do I extend the django oscar customer models fields?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-oscar

How do I extend the django-oscar customer models fields? I have extended the registration form to include more fields, in `apps/customer/forms.py`

```
class EmailUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email address'))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        validators=password_validators)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Confirm password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    #### The extra fields I want to add #####

    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('First name'))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Last name'))
    business_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Business name'))
    business_address = forms.CharField(label=_('Business address'))
    city = forms.CharField(label=_('City'))
```

I have also extended the `[AbstractUser][1]`'s fields in `apps/customer/abstract_models.py`.

```
class AbstractUser(auth_models.AbstractBaseUser,
                   auth_models.PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base user suitable for use in Oscar projects.

    This is basically a copy of the core AbstractUser model but without a
    username field
    """
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(
        _('First name'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(
        _('Last name'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('Staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('Active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'),
                                       default=timezone.now)
    #######################################
    # Additional user fields I have added #
    #######################################
    business_name = models.CharField(
        _('Business name'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    business_address = models.CharField(
        _('Business address'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(
```

However, when a user is created, the additional fields are not getting saved to the database. Is there a better way of extending the customer model to include additional fields I'm not aware of?

When I try to debug in the shell, I run into the issue where the model is not callable:

```
>>> from apps.customer.abstract_models import *
>>> mg = UserManager()
>>> mg.create_user('testemail@test.com', 'testpassword', buisness_name='test_business')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<my_working_dir>/apps/customer/abstract_models.py", line 34, in create_user
    last_login=now, date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure the instructions given in [django oscar'](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/howto/use_a_custom_user_model.html)s docs will work, as that is for customizing methods, not fields on the model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + get_core_apps(
    ['apps.shipping',
     'apps.checkout',
     'apps.partner',
     'apps.catalogue',
     'apps.customer',
     ])


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customer.User'
```

Comment: It's perfectly possible to add fields to the model. Your issue is that your app isn't being loaded. To help us identify the issue, please post: details of where you have create this new code (what files/directories relative to your project root), `INSTALLED_APPS` and `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings.

Comment: I would extend an address model instead of user model. Address will have is_default attribute and foreign key to user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues that I can see, resolving which will hopefully fix your problem:

1. Move your subclass of `AbstractUser` into `apps/customer/models.py` which is where Django looks for models. You've put it in `apps/customer/abstract_models.py` which is a non-standard location for storing models (Oscar does this for abstract models only - you are not supposed to mirror this location yourself). Django will not find them there.
2. Change your class name to `User` instead of `AbstractUser`, because your final model is not abstract. You are also specifying `customer.User` in your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` - these two need to match.
3. The model class you have posted above is incomplete  so we cannot tell - but make sure that it doesn't contain `abstract = True` in the `Meta` class.
4. Run `manage.py makemigrations` which should create migrations for your new user model (if it doesn't then there's still something wrong with your app structure). (Next run `manage.py migrate`).
5. Don't forget to import the rest of the (core) customer models at the bottom of your `models.py`: `from oscar.apps.customer.models import *`. Without these you will lose all the other models that live in the core customer app.

You should also take note of the warning in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) regarding changing the user model (emphasis mine):

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure.
>   It changes the tables that are available, and it will affect the
>   construction of foreign keys and many-to-many relationships. If you
>   intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any
>   migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.
>
> **Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported
>   by makemigrations and will result in you having to manually fix your
>   schema, port your data from the old user table, and possibly manually
>   reapply some migrations.**

Comment: I have performed these changes, but now I am having issues with the auth | user model conflicting with my customized customer user model. There had been accounts created previously to updating the AUTH_USER_MODEL attribute to customer.User

Comment: This is the inherent risk with changing the user model in place - it is not easy or recommended on an existing database. I have added to the answer some warnings from the documentation - can't really help you beyond that.

Comment: can I just set the model using = get_user_model() in the class, and then adding the fields on top of it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You could try setting your model's `Meta` class to use the same table name as before (`db_table = 'auth_user'`) and see if the migrations work then. If not then you either need to manually fix up the table, or consider an alternative approach (e.g., a [profile model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)).

Comment: alright, I manually fixed up the tables, and the users have transferred to the new auth model now.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like all the tables were not fixed by migrations, there are still server errors regarding ProgrammingError: column partner_partner_users.<my_appuser>_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...tner_users" INNER JOIN "user_<my_appuser>" ON ( "partner_p...

To solve this, will I have to manually edit the table names in psql with ALTER TABLE? or is there a way to do it through migrations/python shell?

Comment: I think you will have to manually alter the table names. You could conceivably write a migration to do it but I don't think it would be any quicker/easier.